# What is the difference between KL-divergence, JS-divergence, Wasserstein distance and MMD?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, autoencoder, probability, metric

I was reading about different distribution distances, and came across

- Kullback-Leibler divergence
- Jensen-Shannon divergence
- Wasserstein distance
- Maximum mean discrepancy (MMD)

The book was too abstract for me to absorb. What are the differences between them, actually?

Comment: Do you care about those four distances specifically or are you asking about distances in general and why there are multiple?

Comment: I care about the four distances specifically